# Writing function with an if statement which executes when the statement is NULL or a string equivalent

Tags: r, function, if-statement, null

I would like to have an if statement which executes when the statement is NULL or a string equivalent:

```
somefun <- function (number1, number2, type=NULL) {
if (is.null(type) | type == "sum") {
    print(number1+number2)
    } else if (type == "product") {
    print(number1*number2)
    }}
# So that the two following lines lead to the same result

somefun(1,4)
somefun(1,4,type="sum")
```

The first one however gives the error:

```
Error in if (is.null(type) | type == "sum") { : 
  argument is of length zero
```

How should I write the syntax?

Comment: How about setting type="sum" by default?

Comment: I agree with the above statement; I think it might help if we knew the intent of this function...

Comment: @user2974951 You are completely right, that slipped my mind for second..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of those instances where you need to use `||` over `|`

```
somefun <- function (number1, number2, type=NULL) {
if (is.null(type) || type == "sum") {
    print(number1+number2)
    } else if (type == "product") {
    print(number1*number2)
    }
}


> somefun(1,4,type="sum")
[1] 5
> somefun(1,4,type=NULL)
[1] 5
> somefun(1,4)
[1] 5
```

If I can make a suggestion though:

```
somefun2 <- function (number1, number2, type=NULL){
    if(is.null(type)){
        type <- "sum"
    }
    switch(type,
           "sum" = number1 + number2,
           "product" = number1 * number2
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the suggestion. Is there any additonal benefit apart from the improved readability?

Comment: I was thinking if you added more functionality to what the "type" could do... Like... "Divide" etc could just add to the switch instead of more if tests